Create triangulated faces from edge loop in one step
I have a very large mesh (18M verts, 37M tris) that I need to manually clean up some areas of. (Oof.) Currently I'm cleaning up some long, thin holes (~100 edges on each side, two edges at the ends) by selecting an edge loop around the hole, pressing F to fill with a single face, and then using Face > Triangulate Faces. Because this mesh is so large, and this computer is not super fast, it takes ~30 seconds to create the face, and ~20 seconds to triangulate it. It would make my easier if I could combine those.
Is there a way to kick off a single command that will do the equivalent?
I see that Triangulate Faces shows the shortcut of Ctrl-T, but for some reason typing F and then Ctrl-T immediately does not end up queueing the second command; I have to wait until the face is created.
Blender 4.2 running on Ubuntu/Snap Linux, if it matters.


Can you not just put a triangulate modifier on the object?

@Jakemoyo Answered with a screenshot; the vast majority of the mesh is quads; stitched together with tiny seams that don't line up, and need to be triangulated.

If you press Alt+F when in edit mode it will use the older "Fill Face" operator which automatically fills with tris. You probably have the F2 addon activated which makes it to where "F" fills with an ngon.

@Jakemoyo Perfect! Thank you. Care to post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

If you press Alt+F when in edit mode it will use the older "Fill Face" operator which automatically fills with tris. You might have the F2 addon activated which makes it to where "F" fills with an ngon.


This works nicely most of the time. In a few cases, Face > Fill produced triangulation I didn't like (creating many, much longer edges) while F, Triangulate Faces produced the desired result.
